# Java: passing a label identifier as a string

Tags: java, label, panel

I have 4 or 5 if statements controlling a **label** and a **panel** and I have *16 labels and panels*.

At the moment I would like to shorten this by passing the label and panel identifiers into another method and have tried doing this as a `String` like this

```
String panel="fourFour";
String label="lFourFour";
imaging(panel, label, damage, 4, 4);

public void imaging(String panel, String label, int[]damage, int x, int y){

    if (Game.here(x,y)==1) {
        Color myColor = Color.decode("#8C0834");
        panel.setBackground(myColor);
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Space.jpg"));
    }
```

However I seem to not be able to do this.

Is there anyway to pass the label and panel identifiers into another method?

Comment: In the `imaging` function, `panel` is a String, but you are calling `setBackground()` on it, which is not a String method.  If you really want to use a String to identify your panel, you'll need a `Map<String, JPanel>` to keep track of the links between String names and actual panel objects.  But a bigger question is why are you passing these strings around, rather than panel references to begin with?

Comment: I'm trying to make a method that could be called up to deal with all 16 panels and labels with the 4 or 5 if statements.  Right now I have 16*5 If statements on my page and it looks messy.  If I could pass the label and panel identifiers into this method I could have 5 If statements only, but I need a way of passing the label and panel in otherwise i'm left with the 16*5 if statements instead of the 1.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a specialized class for such an often used feature, e.g.:

```
public class DamagePanel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel label;

    public DamagePanel(final String ident) {
        label = new JLabel(ident);
        this.add(label);
    }

    public String getIdent() {
        return label.getText();
    }

    public void reportDamage(int[]damage, int x, int y) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You could of course also use a separate field as "ident" if you don't want to couple ident and label text...